# Use group by with substring

Tags: sql, group-by, substring

I have data that looks like the following, where the first six digits are a date and the last four a sequence.

```
010219.0013
010219.0081
010219.0082
010319.0063
010319.0099
```

I simply want to know how many of each sequence are on each date. The statement:

```
select left(invoice,6) IV from InvData order by IV
```

works exactly as you'd expect.  However this statement:

```
select invoice IV from InvData order by IV group by IV
```

gives an incorrect syntax error.  Why?

Comment: `group by` needs to come before `order by` in the syntax.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: why do you want group by and order by, do you know order in which statements should be written and logical processing order. t-sql  statements should follow this order `where`, `group by`,`having`,`order by`, and why you are using `group by`?

Comment: Putting group by first simply changes the error to "invalid column name 'IV'"

Comment: DBMS Is SQL Server Express

Comment: Expected result is a list of dates with their frequencies (i.e. how many sequence numbers appeared for a particular date, which is the first 6 characters).

Comment: Having group by and order by may well be incorrect.  The desired result is simply a list of dates and their respective counts.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases -- including SQL Server -- do not allow table aliases in the `GROUP BY` clause.  One simple method is to repeat the expression:

```
select left(invoice, 6) as IV
from InvData 
group by left(invoice, 6)
order by IV  -- is allowed in the `order by`
```

In SQL Server, you can also use a lateral join to define the value:

```
select v.IV
from InvData id cross apply
     (values (left(invoice, 6))) v(IV)
group by v.IV
order by v.IV;
```

Of course, you don't need a `GROUP BY` at all for your original query.  `SELECT DISTINCT` would suffice if you have only that one column.

Answer (score 0):

if the The Syntax Error is like this : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'
it is because order by always should use as the last part of your query.

if not , it is from your group by syntax Go and read about GROUP By clause

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select Left(TestValue,6) AS  TestValue 
from tbltest 
group by TestValue 
order by TestValue
```

You can use this Query....